# Logic Translation with Different Ground Reference

Tags: digital-logic, logic-level

I have two chips which communicate with each other using 1.8v CMOS I/O (1Mbs UART). One chip is on the normal 0v ground plane, but the second chip's ground is at .7v (so its I/O operates at 2.5v for high and .7v for low with reference to first chip's 0v ground).

Im trying to figure out the best way to translate these logic levels so I/O works correctly between them. One option is to just connect them with no level shifting, in which case the the first chip would be seeing 2.5v instead of 1.8v for high (it should be able to tolerate), and .7v for low instead of 0v (which would probably not be reliable for 1.8v low logic which is around .45v to be safe).

Other option is to use something like TXS0102, with its ground referenced to 0v. Two questions with this, the low .7v signal from Chip 2 will be fed to the input of the TXS0102, but will this be low enough to trigger a 0v output for chip 1? Second when chip 1 is sending a low signal to Chip 2, since it will be driven down to 0v chip 2 will see that as -.7v. Will this cause issues with the logic gate over time if its logic gate keeps seeing negative voltage for low?

Am I overcomplicating this an is there a simpler way to do this with voltage dividers for slow 1Mbs logic?

Comment: It seems as though there's a diode in the ground lines. I'd try and get rid of that first. It's seldom a good idea and may bite you in other ways later.

Comment: Diode in the ground lines? The voltage difference between the grounds planes is supposed to be there and is by design...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will shift the voltages with 0.7V

It will also work with bidirectional signals as you see.

Th resistors are chosen for a 1.8 mA but you can change them down to 470 ohm (3.8mA) if you have faster signals.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyfAbf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: interesting...didnt think about diodes. This makes sense going from high side (2.5v signal) to low side, since the diode will knock it down to 1.8v for high single and the low .7v will go to 0v, but not really understanding how this would work for translating 0v low -> .7v and 1.8v high to 2.5v.

Comment: @electronuts The diode is allways forward conducting , the  low side voltage will allways be 0.7 lower than high side voltage. For unidirectional signals you can skip the resistor on the driver side.

Comment: @electronuts It's not original , it's from the microchip pic tips and tricks document, just adapted for two ways because it wasn't specified wether you use bidirectional or unidirectional signals.

Comment: Right that makes sense High side TX to low side RX, but I'm not seeing how this would work for low side TX to high side RX....Its UART so each chip has two unidirection RX/TX lines. Here is a visualization of what I'm trying to ask https://imgur.com/JdKCgmS

Comment: @electronuts Yes ,it will work,  the anode will be allways 0.7 higher than the catode no matter the driver side. The current flows from high side voltage, R, diode,driver output to the low side ground . The diode is allways forward biased. It will work for low side driver to. In this case don't use R on the driver side (for unidirectional signals) .

Comment: nice just did a quick breadboard mockup and seems to work fine, are both pull up and pull down resistors needed going from high to low? Without the R on the low side driver wouldn't current flow into the driver so better to leave it?

Comment: @electronuts It's not needed because it'shorted by the driver output anyway.

Answer (score 1):

"...will this be low enough to trigger a 0v output for chip 1?"

Possibly not. It is well above the VIL for the TXS0102.

"Will this cause issues with the logic gate over time if its logic gate keeps seeing negative voltage for low?"

Probably. It is below the absolute minimum rating for the input of the TXS0102.

You could do some workarounds with voltage dividers if you don't mind drawing a bunch of extra current, slowing the traffic down, etc. But really, you should consider why you need an offset in grounds and eliminate it with some other solution. There's a reason this isn't a standard thing to do.

Comment: unfortunately its part of the design and not something that can be "eliminated"

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with an amplifier OPA564, which have control bits referenced to the negative power supply (-12V in my case), and I need to shift them to the processor levels referenmced to ground at 0V.

I found 2 solutions, but I was not able to find a simple level shifter IC.

1. luxury and simple with digital isolator (ISO7021DR for example)
2. Transistor based translator, cheap but uses many components, and must deal with pull-up (not necessary for me)

[image: transistor based translator]